# Broken stick regression linear mixed effect models

Tags: r, breakpoints, lme4, piecewise

I am trying to fit a broken stick model to longitudinal data. I am unable to reproduce data, here is the first six observations:

```
         pid    arm pday pardens  logpd
1 MOB2004_002     SP    0   40973 10.621
2 MOB2004_002     SP    1   91404 11.423
3 MOB2004_002     SP    2   14342  9.571
4 MOB2004_002     SP    3       0  0.000
5 MOB2004_002     SP    7       0  0.000
6 MOB2004_003 SP/ART    0   11428  9.344
```

and a plot showing the means of 'logpd' at each day (note: it is clearly non-linear, but I am specifically asked to use broken stick assuming the lines are linear):

[image: interaction plot]

The breakpoint is set at day 2. I have found the following syntax from:

(1) [bp1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/estimating-the-break-point-in-a-broken-stick-piecewise-linear-model-with-rando/19777#19777)

(2)[bp2](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can-I-still-do-a-piecewise-broken-line-regression-in-R-if-I-used-the-same-animals-many-times)

The first consist of creating new parameters, as with segmented linear regression:

```
bp = 2
b1 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, bp - x, 0)
b2 <- function(x, bp) ifelse(x < bp, 0, x - bp)

#Mixed effects model with break point = 2

(mod <- lmer(logpd ~ arm * b1(pday, bp) * b2(pday, bp) + (b1(pday, bp) + b2(pday, bp) | pid), data = q1))
summary(mod)

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              2.0071     0.1782 291.5626   11.26  < 2e-16 ***
armSP/ART               -2.0949     0.2520 289.3692   -8.31  3.7e-15 ***
b1(pday, bp)             3.3350     0.1103 305.7435   30.24  < 2e-16 ***
b2(pday, bp)            -0.3713     0.0488 438.5265   -7.61  1.7e-13 ***
armSP/ART:b1(pday, bp)   0.3178     0.1562 303.0042    2.03    0.043 *  
armSP/ART:b2(pday, bp)   0.3972     0.0691 437.3673    5.75  1.7e-08 ***
```

The second using indicator variables:

```
mod.1 = lmer(logpd ~ arm * I(pday * (pday <= 2)) * I(pday* (pday > 2)) + (1 | pid), data = q1)
summary(mod.1)

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        7.4796     0.2001 1051.4035   37.37  < 2e-16 ***
armSP/ART                         -1.4758     0.2845 1048.5079   -5.19  2.5e-07 ***
I(pday * (pday <= 2))             -2.4792     0.1469 1142.4166  -16.88  < 2e-16 ***
I(pday * (pday > 2))              -1.1930     0.0429 1151.6921  -27.78  < 2e-16 ***
armSP/ART:I(pday * (pday <= 2))   -0.5121     0.2076 1138.0203   -2.47   0.0138 *  
armSP/ART:I(pday * (pday > 2))     0.1609     0.0610 1148.1222    2.64   0.0084 **
```

The results are extremely different, the second model seems correct based on the plot. But I don't understand why they would be so different?

Comment: at  a quick glance: do you need `I((pday-2) * (pday <= 2))` (and the corresponding adjustment for the other term) in the second model?

Comment: Yes, that is what makes it a broken stick regression.